Auto-complete for available functions within an API
I'm working with an API called IXnetwork and I have an issue with the auto completion of the objects.
For example how the auto-complete looks like.
When I'm assigning a variable to an object in the following manner:
topology = ixnetwork.Topology.add(Vports=vports[0])
I won't get the auto complete for all the functions that the object has (e.g when issuing topology. I won't see the list of available functions but they will get executed if called correctly).
I will get the auto complete for all the functions if I use the following command.
topology = ixnetwork.Topology.find(Vports=vports[0])
Now after executing this command I'll get the auto-complete of the available functions under that object when issuing
topology.
Is there any chance I could tell the IDE that the object "topology" can use the functions that are available for the ixnetwork.Topology?

What IDE are you using? Please [edit] and add the respective tag. This is all about your IDE setup and not about the API. Having a [mre] would certainly be a plus, though.

topology: ixnetwork.Topology = ...?
